# ask about server send json and client receiver for process [php] not work when server have condition e.g if else?

Tags: php, json

Ask about server send json and client receiver for process [php] not work when server have condition e.g if else?

It's ok when I use this code.

send.php

```
{"text": "aaa","number": "111"}
```

receive.php

```
<?PHP
$url = "http://www.example.com/send.php";
$json = @file_get_contents($url, true);
$decode = json_decode($json, true);
$number = $decode[number];
echo $decode[number];
?>
```

But when I change `send.php` to this code in receive.php not `echo $decode[number];`

```
<?php
$test = "111111";
if ($test != '')
   {
?>
       {"text": "aaa","number": "111"}
<?PHP
   }
else
   {
?>
       {"text": "bbb","number": "222"}
   }
?>
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: error in new file <?php
$test = "111111";
if ($test != '')
{
    ?>
       {"text": "aaa","number": "111"}
<?PHP
   }
else
   {
?>
       {"text": "bbb","number": "222"}
       <?php 
   }
?>

Comment: @Faraz hmm? Care to explain a little more...

Comment: in new send.php <?php was missing. before last } so it was an invalid php file. add it in comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include the `<?php` to close the if statement, so that `}` is being sent in the response (making the response invalid JSON).

A better approach is to work with an array or object, then JSON encode it:

```
$output = array(
    'text' : 'aaa',
    'number' : '111'
);

if($test == ''){
    $output['text'] = 'bbb';
    $output['number'] = '222';
}

echo json_encode($output);
```