# Ask about server send json and client receiver for process [php] not work when server have tag <head></head>?

Tags: php, json

please read before

Not duplicate with [ask about server send json and client receiver for process [php] not work when server have condition e.g if else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23809544/ask-about-server-send-json-and-client-receiver-for-process-php-not-work-when-s)

It's ok when i use this code.

send.php

```
{"text": "aaa","number": "111"}
```

receive.php

```
<?PHP
$url = "http://www.peveea.com/send.php";
$json = @file_get_contents($url, true);
$decode = json_decode($json, true);
$number = $decode[number];
echo $decode[number];
?>
```

but when i change send.php to this code (add tag haed) in receive.php not echo $decode[number];

```
<head>
<title>something</title>
<?head>
{"text": "aaa","number": "111"}
```

Comment: You sent something that isn't JSON. How can you parse something with json_decode if it's not json? Please use some common sense before asking such questions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is not HTML.

You cannot have a `<head>` element in a JSON file.

It makes the JSON invalid, so it cannot be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

your file `send.php` contain html so it is not a json file

so when you use `$json = @file_get_contents($url, true);`

`$jsnon` get the html code so it cant be parsed using `json_decode()`

if you print `$json` you can understand that.